# Are there any programming languages in which arrays are not zero-indexed?

Tags: arrays, programming-languages

Are there any programming languages in which arrays are not zero-indexed?

I.e. the first element of an array is

```
array[1]
```

and not

```
array[0]
```

Comment: BTW please google before posting, your question title as a query returns the relevant Wikipedia page & Stack Overflow question in the first places.

Comment: Also, in Perl it used to be possible to specify the first index via `$[`.

Comment: Sure, I thought that this was a more proper place to have this question answered, than some random Google search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28array%29#Array_system_cross-reference_list) the following languages are 1-indexed...

```
ALGOL 68,
APL,
AWK,
CFML,
COBOL,
Fortran,
FoxPro,
Julia,
Lingo,
Lua,
Mathematica,
MATLAB,
PL/I,
RPG,
Sass,
Smalltalk,
Wolfram Language,
XPath/XQuery
```

Comment: Technically, Fortran does not need to be 1-indexed. The programmer can customise this, but 1 is the default.